# Inheritance of button

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I designed a button

How do I inherit the rest of this button?

[image: button]

---

Does this method of inheritance is true?

mycode :

```
    public class MyButton : Button
{

    public MyButton()
        : base()
    {
        // set whatever styling properties needed here
        this.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        this.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("yes");
    }
}
```

Why not change the background color?

[image: background color]

---

All properties are subject to change

Except the background color

Is this a normal thing

No solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit the rest of this button"? Do you want the other 9 buttons to look the same as your custom one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a new class, subclass the standard Button, and make your style adjustments in the constructor. Once that's done, rebuild your project, and your new component should appear in the Toolbox in the top section. Use it instead of the standard Button and you should be good to go.

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton() : base()
    {
        // set whatever styling properties needed here
        ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: This act is called inheritance?

Comment: Yes, but are you sure you want to derive a class simply to change the ForeColor?

Comment: @wj32 Well, this was sample code. Normally, no, but the OP's example showed a heavily styled button where more properties would need to be changed.

Comment: @ehsan_d18 This is inheritance in the sense that you're subclassing the original Button class. So 'MyButton' inherits from 'Button'.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assumimg what you want is: defining 10 buttons, and styling(set several properties of) button1, you want the rest 9 buttons the same as button1. This is not [inheritance in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28VS.80%29.aspx). To meet your requirement, you can get those 10 buttons into one list/collection/array/etc...one way to get the buttons probably looks like:

```
var buttons = container.Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

And then loop the list to set properties:

```
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
   //set the common properties.
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code:

```
this.BackColor = Color.Red;
```